# How to create cloud watch alarm using x-ray traces response time

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-xray, response-time, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm working on setting up a CloudWatch alarm using the average response time derived from X-ray traces. However, when attempting to visualize the metrics on a graph in AWS console, no results are displayed. At the same time, If I change the metric to "ApproximateTraceCount", I can able to view some data in the graph.

Note: The response time data is gets tracked in X-Ray traces. I can able to see it in the AWS console.

I would like to know is X-Ray response time metric is accessible for cloud watch? and why the Response Time metric is not showing up?